# PHP cURL body elements

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to connect our invoice service API to send e-invoices. I have API instructions, but I have no idea how to put all relevant fields to cURL body in the right way. I am using PHP form like this:

```
    $curl = curl_init($url);
// Set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option to true
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Set the CURLOPT_POST option to true for POST request
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Set the CURLOPT_INSECURE to disable certificate
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Set the request data as JSON using json_encode function
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileSize);

// Set custom headers for RapidAPI Auth and Content-Type header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'x-api-mandator-uuid: mandator-api-id',
  'x-api-key: mandator-api-key',
  'Content-Type: application/json'
]);

// Execute cURL request with all previous settings
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Close cURL session
curl_close($curl);
```

This is how body should be formatted:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.address.here' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-api-key: API KEY HERE' \
--header 'x-api-mandator-uuid: MANDATOR ID HERE' \
--data-raw '{
    "routingInstructions": {
        "primaryDeliveryChannel": 3,
        "sentUsingChannel": 0,
        "eInvoiceNumber": "$customer-e-invoice address",
        "eInvoiceOperator": "$eoperator"
    },
    "debtors": [
        {
            "debtorID": "$id",
            "debtorType": 2,
            "businessName": "$customername",
            "businessID": "$businessid",
            "businessOffice": "",
            "personFirstName": "",
            "personLastName": "",
            "co": "",
            "contactPerson": "",
            "personSSN": "",
            "postalAddress": {
                "countryName": "Suomi",
                "countryCode": "FI",
                "streets": [
                    "$customer-street-addr"
                ],
                "city": "$customer-city",
                "zip": "$customer-zip"
            },
            "emails": [
                "$customer-email"
            ],
            "phoneNumbers": [
                "$customer-phone"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "invoiceFile": {
        "data": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZ....",
        "filename": "invoice - einlasku.xml"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "setAssignmentInStatus": 1
```

I have invoice file in xml-format and it should be Base64 coded.
Can somebody guide me how to put all this info to cURL body in correct way?

Answer (score 0):

In the [PHP Curl documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), there is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` which accepts key=>value array so in your case something like

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'routingInstructions' => [
         'primaryDeliveryChannel' => 3
         ...
    ],
    'debtors' => []
    ...
]);
```

However I can see you need to send file, which can be sent using [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php).

I am finding easier to use library such as [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) for advanced HTTP Post.